# What is the difference between RR-intervals and NN-intervals in HRV-data?

Tags: methodology, data, workload, heart-rate-variability, ecg

Heart rate variability (HRV) is often used as a measure of the sympathetic nervous system. One way to quantify HRV is by calculating the Inter-beat interval (IBI), also referred to as the RR-interval. The RR-interval refers to the time between two R-peak of a traditional ECG heart-beat waveform (see Figure 1).

[image]
*Figure 1: Two subsequent heart-beats with component names. The RR interval is the time between two subsequent R-peaks. Picture taken from: http://lifeinthefastlane.com/ecg-st-segment-evaluation/*

However, in a review article by [Shaffer, McCraty and Zerr (2014)](http://journal.frontiersin.org/article/10.3389/fpsyg.2014.01040) they refer to normal-to-normal (NN) intervals instead. This extends to the statistical measures of the RR intervals, such as SDRR, pRR50 ([Urooj, Gupta, Sp & Tandon, 2014](http://innovareacademics.in/journals/index.php/ijcpr/article/viewFile/3396/1314)), i.e., SDNN and pNN50, respectively (Shafer et al., 2014). 
**What is the difference between RR-intervals and the NN-intervals?**

---

#### References

[Shaffer, F., McCraty, R., & Zerr, C. L. (2014). A healthy heart is not a metronome: an integrative review of the heart's anatomy and heart rate variability. Frontiers in psychology, 5, 1040.](http://journal.frontiersin.org/article/10.3389/fpsyg.2014.01040)

[Urooj, M., Gupta, S., Sp, V., & Tandon, M. (2014). REFERENCE RANGE OF HEART RATE VARIABILITY AND VALIDATION IN SUBJECTS WITH ASYMPTOMATIC ELEVATED LIVER FUNCTION ENZYMES. International Journal of Current Pharmaceutical Research, 6(4), 49-52.](http://innovareacademics.in/journals/index.php/ijcpr/article/viewFile/3396/1314)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The difference is rather simple. NN-intervals refer to the intervals between **normal** R-peaks. During a measurement, artifacts may arise due to arrhythmic events or faulty sensors, for example ([Citi, Brown & Barbieri, 2012](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/230638325_A_Real-Time_Automated_Point-Process_Method_for_the_Detection_and_Correction_of_Erroneous_and_Ectopic_Heartbeats)). This may lead to abnormal R-peaks, which may in turn distort the statistical measures. To ensure reliable and valid data, only normal R-peaks are selected. Alternatively, the abnormal R-peaks can be corrected.

In practice, however, RR-intervals and NN-intervals are synonymous (Tarvainen, 2014; [Wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heart_rate_variability)). The use of "NN-intervals" is merely used to emphasize that normal R-peaks were used.

---

#### References

[Citi, L., Brown, E. N., & Barbieri, R. (2012). A real-time automated point-process method for the detection and correction of erroneous and ectopic heartbeats. IEEE transactions on biomedical engineering, 59(10), 2828-2837.](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/230638325_A_Real-Time_Automated_Point-Process_Method_for_the_Detection_and_Correction_of_Erroneous_and_Ectopic_Heartbeats)

Tarvainen, M.P. (2014). Kubios HRV version 2.2: User's Guide.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heart_rate_variability